# heap alloc + free < heap size

Tags: android, heap-memory, native, dumpsys

Follow is part of dumpsys meminfo's outputs:
[image]

We can see:

Native heap size is `65 MB`

heap alloc is `22MB`, while free is about `3MB`

but alloc + free is quite smaller then size.

Why?